# Struggling with how to iterate data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning Python3 and I have a fairly simple task to complete but I am struggling how to glue it all together. I need to query an API and return the full list of applications which I can do and I store this and need to use it again to gather more data for each application from a different API call.

```
applistfull = requests.get(url,authmethod)

if applistfull.ok:
    data = applistfull.json()
    for app in data["_embedded"]["applications"]:
        print(app["profile"]["name"],app["guid"])
        summaryguid = app["guid"]
else:
    print(applistfull.status_code)
```

I next have I think 'summaryguid' and I need to again query a different API and return a value that could exist many times for each application; in this case the compiler used to build the code.

I can statically call a GUID in the URL and return the correct information but I haven't yet figured out how to get it to do the below for all of the above and build a master list:

```
summary = requests.get(f"url{summaryguid}moreurl",authmethod)

if summary.ok:
    fulldata = summary.json()
    for appsummary in fulldata["static-analysis"]["modules"]["module"]:
        print(appsummary["compiler"])
```

I would prefer to not yet have someone just type out the right answer but just drop a few hints and let me continue to work through it logically so I learn how to deal with what I assume is a common issue in the future. My thought right now is I need to move my second if up as part of my initial block and continue the logic in that space but I am stuck with that.

Comment: Shouldn't `applist.ok` be `applistfull.ok`?

Comment: You either have to put the second block of code inside the `for app` loop, or collect all the `summaryguid` in a list and loop over that list. Otherwise you're just processing the last app.

Comment: @Barmar - corrected; thank you. Luckily it was just an edit here error.

Comment: Is it the case that you will/would repeatedly request the same `f"url{summaryguid}moreurl"` because you have repeated `summaryguid`s?  Perhaps you might build a dictionary with those as the key and the result of the api the value.  Alternatively, you might look at leveraging the `cachetools` module

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

applistfull = requests.get("url", authmethod)

if applistfull.ok:
    data = applistfull.json()
    for app in data["_embedded"]["applications"]:
        print(app["profile"]["name"],app["guid"])
        summaryguid = app["guid"]
        summary = requests.get(f"url/{summaryguid}/moreurl", authmethod)
        fulldata = summary.json()
        for appsummary in fulldata["static-analysis"]["modules"]["module"]:
            print(app["profile"]["name"],appsummary["compiler"])
else:
    print(applistfull.status_code)
```

Comment: This isn't working exactly how I thought as it iterates the API twice through the list so I will looking at how to optimize that by pulling in the full list in the first call and then iterate that as needed with the second for statement.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).